# Finding gapful numbers doesn’t say true if number is gapful

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am writing a program to figure out whether or not a number is gapful (it is at least 3 digits long and divisible by the number formed by its first and last digits). It works fine, except for when I put in a number that I know is gapful. It says it isn’t. Here is my code:

```
var num = prompt("Enter a number to see if it is gapful.");
var str = num.toString(1);
var firstnum = str.charAt(0);
var lastnum = str.charAt(str.length - 1);
var firstandlast = firstnum + lastnum;
var check = num % Number(firstandlast);
function yesno() {
    if (str.length < 3) {
        document.write("No; it is less than 3 digits long.");
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (check = 0) {
            document.write("Yes; it is at least 3 digits long and evenly divisible by the number formed by its first and last digits.");
            return;
        }
        else {
            document.write("No; it is at least 3 digits long, however it is not divisible by the number formed by its first and last digits.");
        }
    }
}
yesno();
```

Why doesn’t this work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the types of `firstnum` and `lastnum`? If you console.log `firstandlast`, does it hold the expected result of their sum?

Comment: Not their sum. It is the two digits put together.

Comment: `=` and `===` are two different things, check your if condition you have a typo there

Comment: Eg. 210 - 2 and 0 is 20

Comment: ^ @Coder66 Ah, my mistake. I misinterpreted "formed by". All good then :)

Comment: Change `check = 0` to `check == 0`. One equal sign sets the value, two checks the values.

Comment: @Code Maniac and imvain2 you’re right. I often make that mistake.